# Grouping a dataframe and reordering based on date and counts

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe, that is grouped according to the invoice cycle first, then added to a count of clinics in each invoice cycle.

[Dataframe after groupby function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SzZo.png)

I used the following code to add the count column:

```
df5 = df4.groupby(['Invoice Cycle', 'Clinic']).size().reset_index(name='counts')
```

and then this code to set the index and get the dataframe, as seen in the image above:

```
df5 = df5.set_index(['Invoice Cycle','Clinic'])
```

Now, I want to reorder the Invoice Cycle column so the dates are in order 16-Dec, 17-Jan, 17-Feb, 17-Mar, etc.

Then I want to reorder the clinics in each invoice cycle so clinic with the highest count is on the top and the clinic with the lowest count is on the bottom.

Given the values in Invoice Cycle are strings, and not timestamps, I can't seem to do both of the above tasks.

Is there a way to reorder the dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function to transform the date-string into a datetime format:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime 

def str_to_date(string):
    # This will get you the date with the first day of the month (ex. 01-Jan-2017)
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(string, '%y-%b')
    return date

df['Invoice Cycle'] = df['Invoice Cycle'].apply(str_to_date)
# now you an sort correctly
df = df.sort_values(['Invoice Cycle', 'counts'])
```

Comment: Thanks! The issue is that 17-Aug means Aug 2017, but the above code gets me 17 as the date. I'll try to change the date format before trying out your function.

Comment: I edited the answer above. Now the code transforms 17-Dec to 01-12-2017.